# How to build an object of nested elements from a list?

Tags: javascript

From a list of objects, I try to create a nested elements object from

The list is as follows

```
[              
  { 
    label: 'Root',
    data: 173,            
    children: [],  
  },           
  {
    label: 'Root child 1',
    data: 174,                                                                                                                                                        
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: 'Root child 2',
    data: 175,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: 'Root child 3',
    data: 176,
    children: [],
  }
]
```

And I want to turn it into

```
{
    label: 'Root',
    data: 173,
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Root child 1',
        data: 174,
        children: [
          {
            label: 'Root child 2',
            data: 175,
            children: [
              {
                label: 'Root child 3',
                data: 176,
                children: [ ],
              }
            ],
          }
        ],
      }
    ],
  }
```

The logic is that each list item from top to bottom will hold the next item in the children property. This, until there is something to add

The list can have a single element or an undefined number

I wanted to add something that I have tried but I feel long to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `reduceRight` for that

it's like `reduce` but it goes right to left instead of left to right

```js
const data = [              
  { 
    label: 'Root',
    data: 173,            
    children: [],  
  },           
  {
    label: 'Root child 1',
    data: 174,                                                                                                                                                        
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: 'Root child 2',
    data: 175,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    label: 'Root child 3',
    data: 176,
    children: [],
  }
]

const result = data.reduceRight((res, item) => {
  return {
    ...item,
    children: [res]
  }
})



console.log(result)
```